# Как в TableView Javafx заносить списки объектов различных классов?

Tags: java, javafx, gui, tableview, fxml

Пытался сделать `TableView <Object> myTable`, но не прокатило, выдаёт ошибку во время компиляции.
Ошибка возникает в этой строке:

```
tableView.setItems(FXCollections.observableList(joinList));
```

Ошибка:
Error:(65, 18) java: incompatible types: inference variable E has incompatible equality constraints java.lang.Object

Comment: а joinList у вас как объявлен? По хорошему, вам надо сделать единую сущность для таблиц, Object плохо тем, что вам постоянно придеться кастить.

Comment: А как вы собираетесь биндить поля объектов к столбцам? В общем случае можно все классы объектов, при условии что они написаны вами, привести к одному интерфейсу. Возможно вам не нужен `TableView`, а подойдёт `ListView`.

Comment: Andrew Bystov, ваш вопрос натолкнул меня на идею объявить joinList так: List<Object> joinList. И это исправило ошибку, спасибо!